# Nef line bundles over varieties

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be a projective algebraic variety over an algebraically closed field $k$ and $\mathcal{L}$ be a  line bundle over $X$. Suppose we have a decomposition $X=U\sqcup Z$, where $U$ is an open subscheme of $X$ and $Z$ is its complement with reduced structure. Suppose that the restriction of $\mathcal{L}$ to each of them is nef, then can we deduce that $\mathcal{L}$ is a nef line bundle over $X$? (Assume $Z$ has positive dimension)

Note that if $C\subset X$ is a "testing" curve, then 3 cases may happen:

1. $C\subset U$, then the degree of $\mathcal{L}$ has non-negative degree over $C$ according to our condition;
2. $C\subset Z$, same analysis as above;
3. $C$ intersects both $U,Z$ non-trivially. Geometrically thinking, if I am working over $\mathbb{C}$, then I may slightly move the curve such that $C\cap Z$ has dimension $1$ rather than $0$. Then I may see that $\mathcal{L}$ has nonnegative degree on $C\cap U$ and $C\cap Z$, hence their union. But it seems that this is only some intuition, not argument.

I would like to ask whether $\mathcal{L}$ is still nef? And how to give a valid argument?

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider, for instance,
$$
X = \mathbb{P}^1 \times Z = (\mathbb{A}^1 \times Z) \sqcup Z
$$
and let $L$ be the pullback of a line bundle on $\mathbb{P}^1$.
Then the restriction of $L$ to both $U$ and $Z$ is trivial, hence nef. But on the entire $X$ it is nef only if the original line bundle on $\mathbb{P}^1$ is nef.

Comment: Thanks @Sasha! It seems that the counterexamples "essentially" come from "degenerating" cases. May I continue to ask a question: If I really would like to get some nefness criterion for $\mathcal{L}$ by testing on open and closed parts, can we add some extra conditions to exclude such degenerating cases to fix the previous statement?

Comment: I don't think such a criterion is possible. The reason is that the nef condition on $U$ is often void (e.g., if $\mathrm{Pic}(U) = 0$), and it is possible that interesting curves don't show up in $Z$.